# Why is printing iwgetid giving me 0?

Tags: linux, types, raspberry-pi, integer, ssid

I'm reading the Wi-Fi connection of my Raspberry Pi, using the `iwgetid` command.

The output is:

```
wlan0     ESSID:"iPhone"
```

I wrote the following lines in a Python script:

```
import os
print(os.system("iwgetid"))
print(type(os.system("iwgetid")))
```

The output I got was:

```
0
<type 'int'>
```

Why is `print(os.system("iwgetid")` giving me `0` when it's a string?

Answer (score 0):

As quoted from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418618):

> os.system() just runs the process, it doesn't capture the output:
>
> If command generates any output, it will be sent to the interpreter
> standard output stream. The return value is the exit code of the
> process:
>
> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
> the format specified for wait().

To get the output from the Terminal command, use the subprocess module and the command `subprocess.check_output` instead of `os.system`.